# Copy all outgoing messages on Outlook to a different directory

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm trying to configure an "outgoing rule" in Outlook that copies all messages that have been sent via an Exchange account to a different account. My outlook account setup is the following:

[image: List of Outlook Accounts]

Two of the accounts are Exchange accounts, the main one is IMAP. I want to copy all sent mail to the Gmail/IMAP account whenever a message is sent. I tried to do so by configuring an "Outgoing" rule in the following way:

[image: An Outgoing Outlook Rule to Copy E-Mails]

This rule doesn't take effect though and no e-mails are copied to the target folder.

Any advice on how to implement this?

Comment: try creating a simpler rule by only containing one address per condition and see the result. For example, add the condition: 'from ' 'is' 'Account1'

Comment: The same applies with no conditions at all.

Comment: I got the chance to test on one Mac machine and was interested to  find that outgoing rule doesn't work on my side either. I'm using Outlook for Mac 16.27

Comment: Thanks Perry. Same version here.